# Graphene without Django ORM models

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-django

what is best practise to integrate `Graphene-Django` with my Redshift tables without using `DjangoObjectType` conversion of django model as 1st step, which I don't have in my case.

How I can bind these tables with Graphene in `schema.py`.

```
class CategoryType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ("id", "name")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement **ObjectType** from Graphene, not **DjangoObjectType**. Then indicate your Redshift fields from category table.

```
import ObjectType from graphene

class CategoryType(ObjectType):
    id = ... 
    name = ...
```